# Best practice rounded corner images on the web

Tags: javascript, css, image

Assuming an appropriate solution can be found (don't need cross browser etc.) -

Would the best way to round corners of an image on the web be CSS/JS,

Or: is it better practice to use images which have has there corners rounded (either thru code on upload or designer's manual labor)?

If available, how about rounding elements - css vs. round corner image (e.g. sprite)?

**Edit** I know CSS is possible, but I assume it makes the browser work harder than just downloading a preeditted image (which would take more effort on server side). The question is not what works, rather what's better.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply create the images with rounded corners, but this would of course increase the time and complexity of generating the images in the first place.

Or, you could also do something just using CSS. Set the image as a background image to a div, and then use the CSS 3 border-radius property to round the corners of the div to give a similar effect.

e.g.

```
div {
    background-image: url(myimage.jpg);
    width: 375px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    border-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    }
```

This will only work in browsers which support CSS 3, but you did mention that cross browser compatibility wasn't an issue.  Just an idea :)

Comment: I know it works, just trying to figure out if generating rounded images would be better. How hard does the browser work for the css?

Comment: @JNF If you mean does it cost more power to do the CSS solution than the image solution, this should not be a concern of yours. Performance gains of this magnitude are insignificant. Even if they weren't, you should have real data and benchmarks before compromising quality/maintainability/etc. for performance.

Comment: @Sprague, Yes, that was the question. And - are they?

Comment: @JNF I don't know, best practice is to use CSS. I think you would have a hard time finding benchmarks for this, but please post them if you do!

Answer (score 0):

You can make an image perfect round by following this code.

```css
.MyImage {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

First we target the image using .MyImage class (you can set whatever you want), Then we set the height and width property equal (you can set whatever you want unless it is equal) so that it becomes a perfect square. Then the border-radius is set to 100%.

Answer (score -1):

All the browsers that support rounded corners now also support rounding corners of images themselves. Like Stef answered, you used to have to use a background image, but this way is far easier.

```
img {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

or

```
img {
    border-radius: 10px 5px 10px 2px;
}
```

In the latest versions of Safari, Firefox, Chrome and even ie9 border radius now works absolutely fine without the prefixes.

It depends how backward compatible you want to be I guess. If you use the background image method to be compatible, you still leave out a whole load of older browsers who don't support border radius, even with prefixes so you really may as well just make the corners part of the image.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score -1):

It's just an extra, for cross browser:

```
img {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```